# Login to PSS (professional surveillance system) failed

Tags: camera, dvr, ip-camera, network-camera

I have connected four cameras to a DVR in my store. To view them with internet I set up the DVR using PSS Professional Surveillance System; it automatically  found the DVR and port forwarded:

[image: DVR port forwarding]

However, when I click 'login' in PSS it says:

> login failed can not find the network host

Comment: i think the problem is port as after i port forworded them when i test them in www.canyouseeme.org it says they are blocked